# ElasticSearch: How to query a date field using a month & date range filter

Tags: elasticsearch, date-range

Currently, I already know how to filter a date range from a (timestamp) date field. That's an easy one:

```
"range": {
    "date": {
        "gte": "2015-11-01",
        "lte": "2015-11-30"
    }
}
```

But how to filter dates when you are interested in ranges based on month like `gte:"02-22"` and `lte:"03-21"`? Is this possible?

Mapping:

```
PUT dob
{
    "mappings": {
        "test":{
            "properties": {
                "dob":{
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                }
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

Query:

```
GET /dob/test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "date": {
                                    "gte": "02-11",
                                    "lte": "03-20"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "script": {
                                "script": "doc.dob.date.getDayOfMonth() >= min && doc.dob.date.getMonthOfYear() <= max",
                                "params": {
                                    "min": 12,
                                    "max": 2
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to output something like `date greater than:02-11 & less than:03-20` but I don't want to change my date type format (`yyyy-mm-dd`) and also I don't want to search it by string. If i am doing something wrong please make me correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify format in date filter like

```
"date":
{
    "gte":"02-22","lte":03-20","format":"mm-dd"
}
```